# Continue numbering after changing subsection in exam class

Tags: numbering, exam

I'm using `\documentclass{exam}` for a solution booklet I'm preparing. It has multiple subsections in a single section. I want the question numbers to continue running, even after the section is changed. I tried using the `\begin{questions}[resume]`, as suggested in a different context, but in vain. I also tried having only one `\begin{questions} ... \end{questions}` block, but here, the subsection is getting an indentation. Any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, enumitem}

\begin{document}

\section{Sec 1}
\subsection{Sub 1}
\begin{questions}
\question Q1
\question Q2

\subsection{Sub 2}

\question Q3
\question Q4
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please add a minimal example of code to play with?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @egreg  Thank you for your quick response! I've edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work, but it *might* interfere with other aspects of `exam`. Proceed with care.

The idea is to save the value of the counter `question` at each `\subsection` command and then use the current value of `question` but added to the previous one, so the counting is progressive.

```latex
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{savequestion}
\preto\subsection{\setcounter{savequestion}{\value{question}}}
\newcommand\newquestionlabel{\the\numexpr\value{question}+\value{savequestion}\relax.}
\patchcmd{\question@number}{\questionlabel}{\newquestionlabel}{}{}
\patchcmd{\question@number}{\questionlabel}{\newquestionlabel}{}{}
\patchcmd{\questions}
  {question@\arabic{question}}
  {question@\the\numexpr\value{question}+\value{savequestion}\relax}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Sec 1}
\subsection{Sub 1}
\begin{questions}
\question Q1
\question Q2
\end{questions}

\subsection{Sub 2}

\begin{questions}
\question Q3
\question Q4
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works! Thank you!!